# Difference between r value and l value

Tags: c, rvalue, lvalue

Does "r- value" comes right of the assignment operator and "l- value" comes left of assignment operator or are they something more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l-value` refers to memory location which identifies an object. l-value may appear as either left hand or right hand side of an assignment operator(=). l-value often represents as identifier.

Expressions referring to modifiable locations are called “modifiable l-values“. A modifiable l-value cannot have an array type, an incomplete type, or a type with the const attribute. For structures and unions to be modifiable lvalues, they must not have any members with the const attribute. The name of the identifier denotes a storage location, while the value of the variable is the value stored at that location.

An identifier is a modifiable lvalue if it refers to a memory location and if its type is arithmetic, structure, union, or pointer. For example, if ptr is a pointer to a storage region, then *ptr is a modifiable l-value that designates the storage region to which ptr points.

---

`r-value` refers to data value that is stored at some address in memory. A r-value is an expression that can’t have a value assigned to it which means r-value can appear on right but not on left hand side of an assignment operator(=).

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lvalue-and-rvalue-in-c-language/

Comment: Does "==" as in relational operator can have  l value or value

Comment: @user12153611 there's no assignment with `==`, so you may have any value on either side

Comment: Ok got the answer

Comment: A reference in the C-Standard may help [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1) See *Footnote (64)* for historical note.